# compress file when uploaded php

Tags: php, zip, compression

okay so i am upload files, they have encrypted names once uploaded, the thing is i want to compress them so when a link is reached it downloads instead of displaying

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";



function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$string69 = generateRandomString();
$date = date("l") . "_" . date("d/m/Y");
$encyptstring = $string69 . "." . $extension;

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "upload/VEMWdk/$string69.$extension")){
} else {
    echo "upload failed :( please contact iHaveDeBestName";
}
?>
```

in function `move_upload_file` instead of having the original '$extention' i would like it to be compressed into a .zip file so it would be like if i uploaded a text file it would save into the upload folder as {randomString}.zip and inside that zip would be the text file.

i have tried other method but all it does is replace files in the zip, i would like to create new zips for each file uploaded

please ignore the sqldB connection, that is going to be used for logging uploads

Comment: sorry for the double sentance at the top

Comment: Hi, but I dont see any attempt to zip anything, or am I missing something

Comment: If you show you r attempts to ZIP the file, someone will probably spot the issue in no time. Rather than showing no attempt which makes the question look like you want the code all written by someone else

Comment: Icepick, you should first read the manual on http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php and only then, if you still have issues implementing your code, ask here.

Comment: Hi upload files, I am human

Comment: @Dale What does that mean?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just saying hello to the first line of the question

Comment: As no reply for 35 minutes, I assume this is a _Do it for me_ request. Closing as Too Broad in that case

Answer (score 2):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip"; //Your Zip File with path

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
$zip->addFile("{your_uploaded_file_with_path}"); // uploaded file
$zip->close();
```